# How to Reduce Time Complexity

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

How can I reduce time for finishing all for loop task? For some reason, I have to used sleep(8)milliseconds.SO,finishing all loops it's need more than 2 hours in CORE i7 CPU and 8GB RAM PC.I'm novice in this field.

```
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        //Task One
        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
                    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
                        for (int k = 1; k <= 1200; k++) {
                            for (int l = 1; l <= 10; l++) {
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(8);
                                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                System.out.println("Task  # A:" + i + " AF: " + j + " C:" + k + " CF:" + l);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

I'm trying another way.This is the right way to reducing time? or suggest me to something better.

```
public class Ask1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        //Total customer 1200
        //1-400 for 
        System.out.println("customer range 1 to 400");
        executorService.execute(new TaskThread(2,10,400)); 
        //401 - 800 
        System.out.println("customer range 401 to 800");
        executorService.execute(new TaskThread(2,10,400));
        //801-1200
        System.out.println("customer range 801 to 1200");
        executorService.execute(new TaskThread(2,10,400));

        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}

class AskThread implements Runnable {

    int agent;
    int finger;
    int customer;

    public AskThread(int agent, int finger,int customer){
        this.agent = agent;
        this.finger = finger;
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= agent; i++) { //changeable
            for (int j = 1; j <= finger; j++) { //fixed
                for (int k = 1; k <= customer; k++) { //changeable
                    for (int l = 1; l <= finger; l++) { //fixed
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        System.out.println("Task One # Agent:" + i + " Agent Finger: " + j + " Customer:" + k + " Customer Finger:" + l);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Imo it is a way too abstract example. Depending on the actual case, usually you can't divide all 3 variables by 3, you can divide only one of them.

Comment: I actually didn't get you. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Btw. your hardware has nothing to do with this if all you do in that loop is sleep. 8 ms of sleep will take about 8 ms on any hardware.

Comment: I'm working with bio metric project. For single matching on average need 8ms time.That's why I sleep it for 8ms. My ultimate goal is to reduce matching time.

Comment: If something takes 8ms and you need to do it 960 000, to optimize it, you need to do it in parallel. How? Well, you've provided no info on that. You could just split it into 8 or 10 threads (your outermost / innermost loop) and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

Let's expand on my comment a little bit. As I said, the example you have provided is way too abstract to give some specific advice how to improve performance.

From what I can tell, you wanted to spread the work equally between multiple threads. In most cases you can't just divide all the "dimensions" by x when creating x threads.

Imagine more concrete task: You have a 2 dimensional matrix, representing a chess board. You want to iterate over all the elements in the matrix and do some operation. You will end up with a loops something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++){
  for (int j = 0; j < dim2; j++){
    \\do something here
  }
}
```

In this example, we have to iterate over `dim1 * dim2` elements.

Let's say we want to divide the work between 4 threads. If you divide both `dim1` and `dim2` by 4, you end up with 4 by 4 matrix, that is 16 parts. It is the most visible when you imagine a physical chess board.

If you have 4 threads you have to divide the work into 4 (usually equal) pieces. In this case, you can either divide both `dim1` and `dim2` by 2 for a total of 4 parts, or only one dimension by 4.

Edit. Probably the same will apply to your problem. If you have x agents, each have 20 fingers, and y customers with 20 fingers each, you probably want to compare each with each.

For 4 threads you can't just take 1/4 of agents, 1/4 of their fingers and compare with some part of customers - and only 1/4 of their fingers. All you can do is to take 1/4 of agents, all 20 of their fingers and compare with all the fingers of all the customers.